# Access the link inside iframe with Python/Selenium and get url

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe

My **main html page** has an iframe it and I to need to get the text `Code: LWBAD` that lives there.

Check picture for a better understanding:

[image]

Bellow is my **main html page source** that has an iframe in it:

```
<td class="centerdata flag"><iframe style="width: 200px; height: 206px;" scrolling="no" src="https://www.example.com/test/somewhere" ></iframe></td>
```

The redirect link (iframe page) has this **html source**

```
<body>
<a href="http://www.test2.com" target="_blank">
<img src="https://img2.test2.com/LWBAD-1.jpg"></a>
<br/>Code: LWBAD
```

So far I can get the complete page source from my **main html page**.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import html5lib

driver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver 2'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get('http://example.com')
try:
    time.sleep(4)
    iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
    driver.switch_to_default_content()

    output = driver.page_source

    print (output)

finally:
    driver.quit();
```

*urls are not accesible from outside of my network that's why I used example.com

Comment: You don't switch to the `iframe` anywhere.

Comment: @Guy I'm new to Python, do u mind showing me where  `switch to the frame` should go ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this:**

```
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
for i in range(0, len(iframe)):
    f = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[i]
    driver.switch_to.frame(i)
    #  your work to extract link
    text = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text
    print(text)
    driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: there you go ! What was the issue though ? Working damn smooth now.

Comment: when `driver.switch_to_default_content()` drive need to find iframe all over again. so i find it using `f = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[i]
`

Comment: i don't have IDE to test my code otherwise i would have suggested it from the start.

Comment: ahhhh ! You are the man ! Last question, simple one, How I can strip the `Code:` part out of the output out so I have only the clean : `LWBAD` ?

Comment: every time do you need to remove Code: ??

Comment: if that so use `text = text.replace("Code:", "")`

Comment: ! clean and simple !

Comment: how do I save the output to a csv file ? What is best to use ? Regular Csv or Panda ? I need to have it printed into a column.

Comment: you should ask seperate question for that

Comment: I did here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861326/python-print-to-specific-column-in-csv if you can have a look please

Answer (score 1):

**you should use**

```
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
 #  your work to extract link
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

**for multiple url**

`find_elements_by_tag_name` will return an array. so use for loop

```
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
for i in iframe:
    driver.switch_to.frame(i)
    #  your work to extract link
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

to get only text

**use**

```
text = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text
```

after  `driver.switch_to.frame(i)`

Comment: Nice ! @Nihail what if  I have multiple iframe urls ? what do I need to change to loop all iframe urls ? And how to print only text ? 'cause now it prints the whole html source.

Comment: what is the text? which do you want

Comment: my output looks like this : `</style>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="http://www.test2.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://https://img2.test2.com/LWBAD-1.jpg></a><br />Code: LWBAD
</body></html>` But I want to print out only the `Code: LWBAD`

Comment: ? any ideas anyone ?

Comment: no luck :( works only when there's a single url :( `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Comment: same error :(  element is not attached to the page document. It works perfect in cases where there's only one iframe, but it give me errors when there's 2 or more iframes :( here's my code : `driver.get('https://www.tenniswarehouse-europe.com/zzz/producttracker_bl.html?ccode=SWIMG030')
    iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
for i in iframe:
 driver.switch_to.frame(i)
 text = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text
driver.switch_to.frame(i)

print (text)`

Comment: let me post that in different answer